# Sorting a dictionary by its value, and then its key if values are equal then outputting a list

Tags: python, sorting

```
map={"a":5, "b":2, "c":7, "d":5, "e":5}
```

output should be:

```
['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b']
```

So, the code should first assort the dictionary in descending order by its value, and then if its value is the same it should sort by the key in ascending order. So far I have...

```
newmap=map
newmap=sorted(newmap.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1,0),reverse=True)
print newmap
```

This gives me the output `[('c', 7), ('e', 5), ('d', 5), ('a', 5), ('b', 2)]`. So, I need to get the e, d, a in ascending order... without messing up the sorts of the numbers. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting is guaranteed to be stable in Python, so all you have to do is sort twice: first on the key, then on the value.

```
sorted_pairs = sorted(sorted(map.iteritems()), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

To get just the keys from this output you can use a list comprehension:

```
[k for k,v in sorted_pairs]
```

P.S. don't name your variables the same as Python types or you're going to be very surprised some day.

Comment: This still gives item pairs, not *just* the keys. The question states that the *output should be `['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b']`*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks. I've made an edit. I must admit that your solution is simpler, although I think mine is applicable to more situations.

Comment: It takes 150% more time than mine though (with the undecorate step).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't really understand what the sort is doing the second time through. Is it possible to write the sorts out on two different lines? Or would that compromise the sorting of the keys?

Comment: @user2943615: The first sort sorts items by key, forward sorted, the second sort sorts items by value, reversed. Items with the same value remain in the same order as before they were sorted the second time.

Comment: @user2943615 yes certainly you can separate the two sorts without affecting the results. The first sort works as a sort of tie-breaker for the second sort, which is the main one.

Answer (score 6):

In my answer, I replaced `map` with `dct` to not mask the built-in function.

Sorted keys by inverse value, then by key in ascending order:

```
sorted(dct, key=lambda k: (-dct[k], k))
```

By turning the value into a negative number, this sorts on value in reverse, while keys are sorted in ascending order.

Demo:

```
>>> dct = {'a': 5, 'c': 7, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 5}
>>> sorted(dct, key=lambda k: (-dct[k], k))
['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'b']
```

Timing comparisons:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("sorted(dct, key=lambda k: (-dct[k], k))", 'from __main__ import dct')
4.741436004638672
>>> timeit.timeit("map(operator.itemgetter(0), sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda i: (-i[1], i[0])))", 'from __main__ import dct; import operator')
7.489126920700073
>>> timeit.timeit("map(operator.itemgetter(0), sorted(sorted(dct.iteritems()), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))", 'from __main__ import dct; import operator')
10.01669192314148
```

Comment: At this point, you might as well sort `map.items()` ... `sorted(map.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))`

Comment: @mgilson: And then you have to un-decorate again. This is just as efficient.

Comment: Am I missing something?  I thought that would give the output that OP wanted (no undecoration necessary...)

Comment: @mgilson: look at the *start* of the question. It asks for the *keys* in the sorted order. Right there where it says *output should be*.

Comment: @mgilson: my version is almost twice as fast as the `dct.items()` version with `map(itemgetter(0), ...)` undecorating.

Comment: I don't know that you can really claim a factor of 2 speedup in general.  The undecorating is a simple O(n) step vs. sorting which is O(nlogn).  For small n, there isn't much difference between O(nlogn) and O(n), but for larger n, you might see the sort step start to take more of the time proporitionally.  In any event, I agree that this is correct since OP wants only the keys.  I was initially under the impression that OP wanted the items for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a list like:

```
l = [('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('b', 1), ('aa', 2), ('aa', 3), ('aa', 1)]
```

**Case 1: Expected:** Values lowest first, then for same value, key wise in ascending order.

**Idea:**
Combine key value in a way that numbers get first priority , then keys.

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda y: str(y[1])+y[0])
[('a', 1), ('aa', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('aa', 2), ('aa', 3)]
```

**Case 2: Expected:** Highest value to be shown first. If a key has same value, sort in ascending order of alphabets.

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda y: str(10-y[1]) + y[0])
[('aa', 3), ('aa', 2), ('a', 1), ('aa', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
```